# Ethics of uploading photos taken on holidays

Tags: model-releases

So, I've received [permission to photograph someone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5912/in-which-cultural-regions-is-taking-pictures-of-people-considered-offensive) - what factors should I take into account as to whether it's ok to upload such photos onto the internet?

In my particular case, it's two photos of me and a maiko (apprentice geisha), and one of a maiko dancing, taken during dinner with them. The photos of me with each maiko was a standard part of the dinner (all of the tourists got a photo taken with them), and I assume that others took photos while they were dancing. I suspect that hundreds of people who've had dinner at the same place with the same maikos would have uploaded their photos, but I'm asking to be on the safe side.

I'm planning on asking about this particular case in a geisha-specific forum, but I'm also asking for future reference.

Comment: You could upload them and make the face unrecognisable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of signed statement or writing do I need from a model to own a license on the photo?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/26355/what-kind-of-signed-statement-or-writing-do-i-need-from-a-model-to-own-a-license)

Comment: Take a look at the model release tag: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-releases

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29181/when-do-you-need-a-model-release

Answer (score 1):

Some factors I can think of:

If someone hasn't given permission to take a photo of them, they haven't given you permission to upload it to the internet. Likewise, if someone's reluctantly given you permission to take a photo at all, uploading it is probably not on.

If someone doesn't really know what the internet is, then they can't give informed consent to someone uploading their photos onto the internet. Some people you meet may not have even used the internet. (One maiko I was with claimed that she's never used a computer, though I suspect it's more likely that she just doesn't use one right now).

Privacy issues with internet photos aren't easy. If you aren't careful, geolocation could end up providing information on where someone lives or works. Facial recognition may end up meaning that someone can detect that a person who is now in a professional job used to work at a maid cafe while at university, which may be embarrassing for her.

Some people or organizations *do* have conditions of not uploading photos or videos to the internet. For example, with a company that I didn't use, they [have on their web site](http://www.kyotosightsandnights.com/vip.html)

> **Note**: None of these services are photo sessions for semi-pro or
>   professional photographers/film makers.  All images taken during the
>   entertainment should be for personal use and are not to be sold or
>   used professionally in anyway. No photos or video may be posted on the
>   internet for public display i.e. personal websites, blogs, Youtube,
>   etc.